# How to implement jdbc driver for presto

Tags: java, jdbc, presto, apache-superset

I am setting up a presto server. I have modified the open source jdbc of presto and developed my presto jdbc jar which is used for authentication. I am using db visualizer tool wherein I can copy the jdbc jar file in the path and use it to authenticate my presto db server. I wanted to switch to a web UI and I see many people recommending apache-superset. I see that the apache-superset is written in python. Is there a way to plugin my jdbc driver for presto in apache-superset so I can connect to my database and start querying the data.
I see that under Sources Tab we an add our database but this won't help me in connecting to my environment.

Comment: I saw people using JDBC drivers via py4j in Python. I don't know whether it will work in superset too. BTW for help with development on top of Presto I invite you to `#dev` channel on Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: Why are you trying to write/modify a JDBC driver yourself?

Comment: The default jdbc doesn't have any authentication in it. We modified the jdbc driver to authenticate with our LDAP. Because of this, we cant use the default jdbc presto driver here we need to implement the modified jdbc driver. @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Superset** use **PyHive** package to communicate with **Presto** and also supports authentication. So, If this connector is not enough for your case you can use these approaches:

1. Modify **Pyhive** package for your usage.
2. Use **JayDeBeApi** to use your own JDBC Driver and create your own database connector on superset.